# redefine webapp location - maven standard folder for web resources

Tags: java, maven, web-applications

I have big Java project build with Ant, that I am converting to maven.

How to redefine webapp - maven standard folder for web resources?
I can't move web content, and it is always under active development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html

The property you want to change is "warSourceDirectory"

Answer (score 0):

Solved by

```
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                        <directory>${webapp-folder}</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.jar</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```